# Zero values when selecting year from date in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm trying to select the year in MySQL with PHP with this:

```
session_start();
$school_id = $_SESSION['school_id'];
$section_id = $_POST['section_id'];
$today  = date("Y");

$select_grades_deped = "SELECT * 
             FROM deped_grade_archive 
             WHERE school_id='$school_id'
             AND section_id='$section_id'
             AND year(submission_date) ='$today' ";

$query_check_grades= mysql_query($select_grades_deped) or die (mysql_error());

$check_count = mysql_num_rows($query_check_grades);

if($check_count == 0){
    $return['checked'] = "0";
}
else{
    $return['checked'] = "1";
}

echo json_encode($return);
```

But unfortunately when I tried the following:

```
SELECT year( submission_date )
FROM deped_grade_archive
WHERE school_id = '$school_id'
AND section_id = '$section_id'
```

It returned zero values from my table. I change the data type of `submission_date` into `date` data type because it was `varchar` before but there still no use. Please help guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When changing it to the `date` data type, if you don't set a default value for the column (such as `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`), the value will be `0000-00-00`. Thus, the `YEAR` operation will return `0` as shown.

You'll need to update your `submission_date` column to the time you wish to specify for each row.

Comment: so what default value am I going to put if im getting the date like this date("F j, Y");

Comment: The default value will be `date("Y-m-d", strtotime(date("F j, Y")));` (replace `date("F j, Y")` by the variable that contains your date in the "`f j Y`" format).

Answer (score 0):

try it like that

```
           SELECT YEAR('submission_date')
```

[ref](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year)